# Simplifying a Hessian

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, chain-rule, kronecker-product

Let $b: \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function, $A \in \mathbb R^{d \times m}\;$ and $x \in \mathbb R^d$. Consider the function $f(A) = b(A^T x)$. Let us denote the argument of $b$ as $\theta$. We would like to compute the Hessian of $f$. My calculation suggests that
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial A_{uv} \,\partial A_{st}} = x_s \,x_u \,\frac{\partial^2 b}{\partial \theta_v \,\partial \theta_t}
$$
where the last term is evaluated at $\theta = A^T x$.
Suppose we would like to write this as a Hessian matrix w.r.t. $\text{vec}(A) \in \mathbb R^{md}\;$ which is obtained by vertically concatenating the columns of $A$. It seems to me that this Hessian can then be written as
$$
\Big(\frac{\partial^2 b}{\partial \theta_v \,\partial \theta_t}\Big)_{u,v = 1}^m \otimes xx^T = \nabla^2 b \,\otimes \, xx^T.
$$
where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product and $\nabla^2 b = (\frac{\partial^2 b}{\partial \theta_v \,\partial \theta_t})$ is the [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) of $b$.
I did convince myself that this is true, but checking it is an indexing mess and I might have fooled myself into believing it.

1. Is this correct?
2. Is there a clean way of deriving this?

Comment: You might clarify what $\nabla^2$ signifies here. The physicist's notation for the scalar Laplacian with respect to the $\theta$?

Comment: I have updated the post. It is the Hessian not the Laplacian.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}\def\v{{\rm vec}}\def\p{{\partial}}\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3^T}}\def\E{{\cal E}}\def\F{{\cal H}}$Given
a function $b(\theta)$ and its gradient and hessian
with respect to the vector $\theta$
$$\eqalign{
p=\grad{b}{\theta}\doteq\nabla b
\quad\qquad
Q=\hess{b}{\theta}{\theta} \doteq \nabla^2b \\
}$$
use the relationship $\,\theta=A^Tx\;$ to obtain the
gradient and hessian wrt the matrix $A$.

Start by expanding the differential of the function.
$$\eqalign{
db &= p:\c{d\theta} \\
 &= p:\c{dA^Tx} \\
 &= xp^T:dA \\
G \doteq \grad{b}{A} &= xp^T \qquad&\big({\rm gradient\,matrix}\big) \\
}$$
Now expand the differential of the gradient to calculate the hessian.
$$\eqalign{
dG &= x\,\c{dp}^T \\
 &= x\left(\c{Q\,d\theta}\right)^T \\
 &= x\,d\theta^TQ^T \\
 &= xx^TdA\,Q^T \\
 &= \left(xx^T\cdot\E\cdot Q\right):dA \\
\F \doteq \grad{G}{A} &= xx^T\cdot\E\cdot Q
  \quad&\big({\rm hessian\,tensor}\big) \\
}$$
where $(\!\ \cdot | :\ \!)\,$ denote single|double dot products between fourth-order tensors and matrices
$$\eqalign{
&\E\cdot Q = \sum_{\ell=1}^m\;\E_{ijk\ell}\,Q_{\ell s} 
&\qquad xx^T\cdot\E = \sum_{i=1}^d\;\big(xx^T\big)_{ri}\,\E_{ijk\ell} \\
&\F = xx^T\cdot\E\cdot Q 
&\qquad \F:A = \sum_{k=1}^d \sum_{\ell=1}^m\;\F_{ijk\ell} A_{k\ell} \\
}$$
and $\E$ is the fourth-order identity tensor
$$\eqalign{
\E &= \grad{A}{A} \qquad\implies\quad
\E_{ijk\ell} &= \grad{A_{ij}}{A_{k\ell}} = \delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell} \\
A &= \E:A = A:\E \\\\
}$$

---

An alternative to tensors is to flatten the new variable into $\,a=\v(A)$.
$$\eqalign{
g &\doteq \left(\grad{b}{a}\right) \;=\; \v\left(\grad{b}{A}\right) \\
 &= \v(xp^T) \\
 &= p\otimes x \\
\\
dg &= \v(dG) \\
 &= \v(xx^TdA\,Q^T) \\
 &= (Q\otimes xx^T)\;\v(dA) \\
 &= (Q\otimes xx^T)\;da \\
H \doteq \grad{g}{a} &= Q\otimes xx^T \\
}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\def\tsum{\textstyle\sum}$
For completeness, I want to include the version using index notation.

Denote by $f$ the function $f(A)=A^Tx$. In indices, that is
$$f_i = \tsum_j x_jA_{ji}$$
Denote by $\partial_{st}$ the derivative with respect to $A$, so that $\partial_{st}A_{ji}=\delta_{sj}\delta_{ti}$. Then
$$\partial_{st}f_i = \tsum_j x_j\delta_{sj}\delta_{ti} = x_s\delta_{ti}$$
and $\partial_{uv}\partial_{st}f_i=0$.
Now, by the chain rule and the Leibniz rule you have
$$\begin{aligned}
\partial_{st}(b\circ f) 
&= \tsum_k(\partial_kb\circ f)\cdot(\partial_{st}f_k) \\
\partial_{uv}\partial_{st}(b\circ f) 
&= \tsum_k\partial_{uv}(\partial_kb\circ f)\cdot(\partial_{st}f_k)
+ (\partial_kb\circ f)\cdot(\partial_{uv}\partial_{st}f_k) \\
&= \tsum_{k,l}(\partial_l\partial_kb\circ f)\cdot(\partial_{uv}f_l)\cdot(\partial_{st}f_k) \\
&= \tsum_{k,l}(Hb\circ f)_{lk}\cdot(x_u\delta_{vl})\cdot(x_s\delta_{tk}) \\
&= x_ux_s(Hb\circ f)_{vt},
\end{aligned}$$
as desired.